# Using <xsl:sort> to sort on partial string values

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Once again, I'm not terrible comfortable with the terminology involved with XSLT but I will try my best to explain the issue I am having.

I have the following XML example

```
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>Tim</FirstName>
        <LastName>Browne</LastName>
        <Position>CEO</Position>
        <Email>TBrowne@Infoteria.com</Email>
        <Category>Officer</Category>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Employee>
    [More employees...
</Company>
```

I am trying to sort the above data by their email domain (the stuff that follows the '@'). Here is what I have tried

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Employee">
    <xsl:sort select="substring-after('Email','@')"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Basicly the template that you cant see is just a simple "Make a row in a table for each employee" so there isn't much to see there. My thought process, as you can see above, was that if I can sort on everything AFTER the @ then my solution would be complete.

Example of the output template.

However this seems to break the sorting as it just returns them in the chronological list in which they appear in the xml (First employee, then second etc instead of being sorted) which I assume means there is a problem with the sorting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not bad basically but what is the current output? You need to specify more on how "it breaks".

Comment: Sorry, I amended the question. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote the comment before editing, sorry! Should be updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<xsl:sort select="substring-after('Email','@')"/>` to `<xsl:sort select="substring-after(Email,'@')"/>`.

Comment: God damn it! Thanks guys, sorry for wasting your time with such a pleb problem. That solved it, thanks again.